# Creating a many to many relationship in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I create a relationship table in my migration class that both references are used in an unique index?

```
class CreateDiagnosticHypotheses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :diagnostic_hypotheses, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :accident_indication, index: true
      t.references :forms, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_foreign_key :diagnostic_hypotheses, :accident_indications
    add_foreign_key :diagnostic_hypotheses, :forms, column: :diagnostic_hypothesis_id
  end
end
```

When I run rake db:migrate it tries to create separate indexes. How can I create just one unique index with both :accident_indication and :forms references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create unique composite index:

```
class CreateDiagnosticHypotheses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :diagnostic_hypotheses, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :accident_indication
      t.references :forms

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :diagnostic_hypotheses, [:accident_indication_id, :forms_id], :unique => true

    add_foreign_key :diagnostic_hypotheses, :accident_indications
    add_foreign_key :diagnostic_hypotheses, :forms, column: :diagnostic_hypothesis_id
  end
end
```

I didn't try it myself, however, but I think you've got the idea.

Comment: The only problem is that it generates a long index name and you have to provide one manually. It seems a bit odd it doesn't provide a way to create a composite index by the reference names instead of the generated column names, but that's ok.